How to permanantly disable CHKDSK
I have a 128GB flash drive with Windows 7 installed on it using WinToUSB. I use my pendrive in my home PC to sync my files and also in another PC where there's no keyboard. The problem is, on every boot, Windows requires a CHKDSK check and I don't have time to let it happen, or a keyboard to press a key.
i. I am sure that the hard drives are okay and it's not faulty.
ii. I don't want to flag the internal HDD as "dirty" and let the original users wait for CHKDSK again....
Kindly help me to disable CHKDSK.

"I am sure that the harddrives are okay and it's not faulty" -- OK, but the need for chkdsk indicates that the filesystem(s) keep going corrupt (or at least "not as well as they should be"). It's a problem with data integrity, not with the hardware. The hardware being OK is a good thing, but it does not guarantee the data is OK.

What are the contents of BootExecute within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager, if you replace the contents with autocheck autochk *, you will prevent the next chkdsk of course this doesn’t stop the problem with the file system from reappearing

The data is okay. Whenever I plug in my USB, it scans both the USB's partition and the internal partition every time. When I opened regedit, the value was autocheck autochk * and every time I reboot the chkdsk occurs. I have W10 installed on my internal drive which is a SSD, and it doesn't say for chkdsk

If it occurs during bootup you can use chkntfs /x u: with u being the USB drive letter / the drive you don't want to be checked. This also works through the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager you need to remove all IDs except autocheck autochk *.
Alternatively, you can disable the service shell hardware detection via services.msc.
However I would not recommend it, in my experience, the drive is only scanned once and will be only scanned again if it is removed insecurely. Not sure what causes the drive to be checked, I would assume it's implemented through some kind of flag on the drive or in the Windows registry.
